# TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects

Tags: python, unit-testing, pickle, setup.py, dill

I use `dill` to save ML model to file.

When I run my tests with `python -m unittest` it works. But if I try run tests with `python setup.py test` it getting error `TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects` in raw where I try to save model.

**My settings in setup.py for testing:**

`test_suite='tests',
tests_require=['pytest']`

**Error:**

```
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1055, in save_builtin_method
    pickler.save_reduce(_get_attr, (module, obj.__name__), obj=obj)
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 610, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1260, in save_module
    state=_main_dict)
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/Users/anna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 496, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects
```

Could you help me to know why it doesn't work?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  This is a known open issue for `dill`.  See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/106. Essentially, a serialization function for `PyCapsule` objects has not yet been registered in `dill`.

**Update:** As of
https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/pull/477
`PyCapsule` is now supported.

Comment: Do you mind posting an example of the workaround? I am trying to send a method from a `PyCapsule` class to a Pool - I am not entirely sure how to do this using said pointer method in the link you provide at the end of the ticket.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try harder then and post if I have something.

Comment: my confusion with this answer is that my object doesn't even appear to be a PyCapsule, nor contain one.  I guess the class object does contain a couple of dicts, but i just don't see what my offending component is to cause this problem.  i'm at python 3.7.0, as forced by Blender 2.80 release candidate 2.

Comment: @ofloveandhate: If your object isn't an machine learning model, then I expect it should be a different question... and will attempt to serialize different objects.  Generally, you won't see a `PyCapsule` object.  Post a new SO question.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns As of `dill` version 0.3.1.1 this issue appears to be somehow related with `numpy` versions >1.16.4 where, apparently, dilling of np.arange(3) provide the error, but not dilling of list [0,1,2] for example.

Comment: @maurizio: I'm not seeing that behavior with `arange`, as noted in the GitHub issue.